# NativeScript: Instructions on how to use Material Design on Android <5

Tags: android, material-design, nativescript

How to use Material Design on Android < 5? I added app.gradle to app/App_Resources/Android. This is what I have in there:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"
}
```

But still no luck getting Material Design slider and textfield. Could someone give precise instructions on how to add Material Design in NativeScript apps. Better a link to a repo with an example. Especially I'm interested in slider and textfield elements. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure your activities extend `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the guidance in developer.android.com [here](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) :

> To use material design in your Android apps, follow the guidelines defined in the material design specification and use the new components and functionality available **in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above**.

So basicly the native API is supporting Material design with version 5 and above so you can't implement it on lower versions.

Check also this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) for  further information about maintaining compatibility in different android versions.

EDIT: There are many plugins that are bringing material-design functionallity in NativeScript (for example [cardview](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-cardview)) - however notice that material design is more concept based on different rules so one technique can be considered material desing if used in place and anti-material if used wrong..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about this: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Even in that link If you scroll down to FAQ page you will find section "Why has X widget not been material-styled when running on pre-Lollipop?"